# How to attach data type to Cypress.as alias function

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, typescript-types

I have an object out of which I create an alias named userId

```
cy.wrap(response.id).as('userId');
```

When referencing userId its type is `JQuery<HTMLElement>`

```
cy.get('@userId').then(userId => // userId type is JQuery<HTMLElement> });
```

How does one define the **alias type** when defining the alias?

Intention is to have it as a `number` directly instead of default `JQuery<HTMLElement>`

**EDIT**

I do not want something like this

```
cy.get<number>('@userId').then(userId => // userId type is number });
```

I want to define the type at function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with these two type defns in `cypress.d.ts`

```js
// cypress.d.ts

/**
 * Get one or more DOM elements by selector.
 * The querying behavior of this command matches exactly how $(…) works in jQuery.
 * @see https://on.cypress.io/get
 * @example
 *    cy.get('.list>li')    // Yield the <li>'s in <.list>
 *    cy.get('ul li:first').should('have.class', 'active')
 *    cy.get('.dropdown-menu').click()
 */
get<E extends Node = HTMLElement>(
  selector: string, 
  options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>)
  : Chainable<JQuery<E>>

/**
 * Get one or more DOM elements by alias.
 * @see https://on.cypress.io/get#Alias
 * @example
 *    // Get the aliased ‘todos’ elements
 *    cy.get('ul#todos').as('todos')
 *    //...hack hack hack...
 *    //later retrieve the todos
 *    cy.get('@todos')
 */
get<S = any>(
  alias: string, 
  options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>)
  : Chainable<S>
```

You can "fix" it by reversing the order,

```js
// cypress/support/index.ts

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      // change the order of these two dfns
      get<S = any>(alias: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<S>
      get<E extends Node = HTMLElement>(selector: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<JQuery<E>>
    }
  }
}
```

Now `cy.get('@alias')` types to `any` (because of `get<S = any>`), which is valid since aliases store any type.

But also the `selector` version is getting typed to `any` as well, it seems the identical type signatures make one of the defns redundant.

As Mikhail Bolotov points out, a different command name solves the issue, but I would define it as a custom command in `/cypress/support/index.ts` and call it `getAlias` since it has to work for any type.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it's impossible to derive the type from alias definition to the alias reference.
But you can define it directly on the reference (works in a Typescript file only):

```js
cy.get<number>('@userId').then(userId => // userId type is number });
```

You also can extract a plain function (or add a custom Cypress command) for such a number alias:

```js
function cyNumber(alias: string) : Chainable<number> {
  return cy.get<number>(alias)
}

cyNumber('@userId').then(userId => // userId type is number });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want. It's just constantly repeating `cy.get<number>`
Is there any alternatives? I cannot believe that Cypress team hasn't addressed this issue.

Comment: I updated the answer with a plain function example

Comment: @rmnrdi not behind the answer... but Tnx